# One domain and multiple website in folders

Tags: seo, subdomain

I am going to create a network with one domain, e.g. example.com then going to manage my websites in **folders**. Look below for example:

```
www.example.com/market
www.example.com/freebies
www.example.com/personalblog
www.example.com/shop
```

Consider that all four websites have different design and codes.From seo perspective, is it recommended or I should use **subdomains** or buy **four domains** for each website?

Comment: Asked on webmasters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43725/one-domain-and-multiple-website-in-folders

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use subdirectories to serve different, non-related websites. Sub domains can be considered if the websites have 'some' relation. Separate domains are preferable if the websites have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that a good question.
In SEO, it's great to work **with Silo's technique**. the "market" silo's should deals with one subjet, the "freebies" silo's should deals with another, etc...

Nevertheless, **Google needs to qualified the subject of the global site**. The qualification of homepage is important for a great SEO strategy.

According to Abondance (famous seo french agency), working on subfolder isn't a bad solution, even if working on subdomain seems to be better (even more if different parts of your site is in different languages).

To conclude, i think that your solution **isn't so bad**, but some are thinking that **subdomains are better**, **even more if subjects of every parts are really really differents** in their content, as said by thaJeztah